# Decoding 'raw' string converted to unicode

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding

I have script with fetching some data and parsing it via lxml.

Initially it has `lxml.etree._ElementUnicodeResult` type, but we could easily convert it it `unicode`.

There is some perilous moment.
This unicode string contains raw bytes of string. Although that has type of `unicode` it keeps raw bytes of usual python `str`.

```
label
Out[53]: u'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
```

Is there any way to convert this `unicode` string of raw bytes to raw bytes actually (`str` type on python 2).

I could easily copy-paste it to interactive console and convert it actually to unicode points:

```
'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
Out[54]: '\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'

'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'.decode('utf-8')
Out[55]: u'\u0412\u043b\u0430\u0434\u0438\u043c\u0438\u0440'
```

Comment: There must be a bug in your code if `label` ends up having that value. Show the actual code that produces it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the string using the “latin-1” encoding, which straightforwardly maps the 256 characters U+0000 through U+00FF to single bytes.

```
>>> s = u'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
>>> s.encode('latin-1')
b'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Unicode string was decoded with the wrong codec.  It looks like `latin1`.  You can re-encode it with the same wrong codec, then decode with the correct one.

```
s = u'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80'
print(s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8'))
```

Output:

```
Владимир
```

Better yet, decode it correctly in the first place ;^)

Comment: Strictly speaking, it looks like a utf-8 encoded byte-string with a `u` stuck on the front. Or latin1 mojibake.

Comment: It's UTF-8.  `Владимир` is Russian for `Vladimir`.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was just jokingly (and pedantically) pointing out that it doesn't "look like latin1" (since `Владимир` cannot be encoded in latin1).

Answer (score -2):

Does this help ?

```
str1 = repr(u'\xd0\x92\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd1\x80')
print type(str1)
print str1
# or
print str1[1:]
```